# How to insert a \pagebreak before a \multicolumn?

Tags: longtable, page-breaking, multicolumn

In a long table it is usually possible to insert a `\pagebreak` in front of a row.
If, however, that row begins with a command using `\noalign` (like `\multicolumn` or `\rowcolor`) `\pagebreak` causes a "misplaced \noalign" error.

I have tried inserting a `\\` after the `\pagebreak` but that inserts an undesired empty row.

I have tried getting rid of the empty row by inserting a negative space with `\pagebreak\\[-\baselineskip]` but `\baselineskip` appears to be 0pt.

With the help of `\showthe\baselineskip` I have found that `\pagebreak\\[-\arraystretch\dimexpr12pt\relax]` does what I want - as long as nobody changes the font size.

How do I correctly insert a `\pagebreak` in front of a `\multicolumn` without hard coding the 12pt?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\colorlet{sectionbg}{gray!20}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\eol}{\\\hline}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\rowcolor{sectionbg}\multicolumn2{|l|}{#1}\eol}

\keepXColumns

%TODO: how do I avoid hardcoding the 12pt?
\newcommand{\ltpagebreak}{\pagebreak\\[-\arraystretch\dimexpr12pt\relax]}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{|lL|}
    \hline\endhead
    \section{Section~1}
        1 & Line A \eol
        2 & Line B \eol
        3 & Line C \eol
    \ltpagebreak
    \section{Section~2}
        4 & Line D \eol
        5 & Line E \eol
        6 & Line F \eol
    \section{Section~3}
        7 & Line G \eol
        8 & Line H \eol
        9 & Line I \eol
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you can use \normalbaselineskip

Comment: yes, thank you. If you post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tabularx compiles the tabular twice, the first time to do some measuring, and this doesn't like the pagebreak. You can avoid that with the following test (it is a bit hacky, but tabularx is missing a better test condition.

Regarding the baselineskip: in a tabular you can access it with `\normalbaselineskip`.
And consider to use xltabular instead of ltablex directly. xltabular is maintained.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\colorlet{sectionbg}{gray!20}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\eol}{\\\hline}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\rowcolor{sectionbg}\multicolumn2{|l|}{#1}\eol}

\keepXColumns

%TODO: how do I avoid hardcoding the 12pt?
\let\jakunTXtest\write
\newcommand{\ltpagebreak}{\ifx\jakunTXtest\write \pagebreak\fi}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{.5\linewidth}{|lL|}
    \hline\endhead
    \section{Section~1}
        1 & Line A \eol
        2 & Line B \eol
        3 & Line C \eol
    \ltpagebreak
    \section{Section~2}
        4 & Line D \eol
        5 & Line E \eol
        6 & Line F \eol
    \section{Section~3}
        7 & Line G \eol
        8 & Line H \eol
        9 & Line I \eol
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```