# How to do \nopagebreak in xltabular with \multicolumn and \rowcolor?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, multicolumn, rowcolor

After reading tons of answers here, the docs and log output I have no idea to solve my \nopagebreak issue.

Based on the [How to insert a \pagebreak before a \multicolumn?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/595119/how-to-insert-a-pagebreak-before-a-multicolumn) answer I build this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\colorlet{sectionbg}{gray!20}


\let\jakunTXtest\write
\newcommand{\ltpagebreak}{\ifx\jakunTXtest\write \pagebreak[2]\fi}
\newcommand{\ltnopagebreak}{\ifx\jakunTXtest\write \nopagebreak\fi}


\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\eol}{\cr\hline}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\rowcolor{sectionbg}\multicolumn2{|l|}{#1}\eol}

\keepXColumns


\begin{document}
    \begin{xltabular}{.5\linewidth}{|lL|}
    \hline\endhead
    \section{Section~1}
        1 & Line A \eol
        2 & Line B \eol
        3 & Line C \eol
    \section{Section~2}
        4 & Line A \eol
        5 & Line B \eol
        6 & Line C \eol
    \section{Section~3}
        7 & Line A \eol
        8 & Line B \eol
        9 & Line C \eol
    \section{Section~4}
        10 & Line A \eol
        11 & Line B \eol
        12 & Line C \eol
    \section{Section~5}
        13 & Line A \eol
        14 & Line B \eol
        15 & Line C \eol
    \section{Section~6}
        16 & Line A \eol
        17 & Line B \eol
        18 & Line C \eol
    \section{Section~7}
        19 & Line A \eol
        20 & Line B \eol
        21 & Line C \eol
    \section{Section~8}\ltnopagebreak
        22 & Line A \eol\ltnopagebreak
        23 & Line B \eol\ltnopagebreak
        24 & Line C \eol\ltnopagebreak
    \section{Section~9}
        25 & Line A \eol
        26 & Line B \eol
        27 & Line C \eol
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

I need to keep the section and the following rows together, only allowing pagebreaks after complete sections.

I tried to move the `\nopagebreak` into different places, e.g. right after `\cr`, but no success.

Is there any chance to get this working?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Redefine command `section` as you do, is not smart idea. How you will use it outside `table`? Better is define new command. `xltabular` doesn't need command `\keepXColumns`.

Comment: Thank you :-) I agree that redefining the `section` is not the best way, I just used for the MWE to show my `\nopagebreak` problem as it was in the code I copied from. Thanks for the hint with `\keepXColumns` I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to avoid a break in the wrong place, force one in the right place.

For example, if you want to avoid a lonely section 8 at the bottom of the page,
the command `\sectionxy` will add a blank row in the desired place, thus making (longtable) a page break and starting section 8 on the new page.

I changed the name of your command `\section` to `\sectionx` to avoid conflicts with the proper `\section`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xltabular}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\colorlet{sectionbg}{gray!20}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\newcommand{\eol}{\\ \hline}
\newcommand{\sectionx}[1]{\rowcolor{sectionbg}\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{#1}\eol}  % old \section

\newcommand{\sectionxy}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\ \rowcolor{sectionbg}\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{#1}\eol} % added <<<

\begin{document}
        
    \begin{xltabular}{.5\linewidth}{|lL|}
        \hline\endhead
        \sectionx{Section~1}
        1 & Line A \eol
        2 & Line B \eol
        3 & Line C \eol 
        \sectionx{Section~2}
        4 & Line A \eol
        5 & Line B \eol
        6 & Line C \eol
        \sectionx{Section~3}
        7 & Line A \eol
        8 & Line B \eol
        9 & Line C \eol
        \sectionx{Section~4}
        10 & Line A \eol
        11 & Line B \eol
        12 & Line C \eol
        \sectionx{Section~5}
        13 & Line A \eol
        14 & Line B \eol
        15 & Line C \eol
        \sectionx{Section~6}
        16 & Line A \eol
        17 & Line B \eol
        18 & Line C \eol
        \sectionx{Section~7}
        19 & Line A \eol
        20 & Line B \eol
        21 & Line C \eol
        \sectionxy{Section~8} % added <<<<<<
        22 & Line A \eol
        23 & Line B \eol
        24 & Line C \eol    
        \sectionx{Section~9}
        25 & Line A \eol
        26 & Line B \eol
        27 & Line C \eol
    \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Simon, as the table is generated from a template and we don't know how many records and sections we have. It is possible that a section is longer than page or we have 5 sections with only 3 row on one page. Starting each section on a new page will lead us to a lot of blank space. So I'd love to see `\nopagebreak` working. :-)

Comment: @Mario Minati I think you misunderstood:  `\sectionxy` is applied manually, like `\nopagebreak`, only to the sections you want to keep in one piece. The solution does not starts every section in a new page!  (`\sectionx` is just a new name for your `\section`).

Comment: My issue is that I don't know where the pagebreak belongs to, as the document is generated and the number of ections and entries per section differs.

Comment: @Mario Minati I understand. But any solution so far involves manual intervention, after the table is first generated and composed. Not different from placing the floats or dealing with overfull warnings.

Comment: I thought that the `\nopagebreak` command was introduced for such a situation, to tell the latex engine where to put breaks. But from reading SE up and down I'm thinking that this command is working very flaky.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with `longtblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: `\nopagebreak` works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewTableCommand{\mysection}{\SetCell[c=2]{gray9}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {Long Table},
]{
  width = 0.5\linewidth,
  colspec = {|lX[l]|},
  hlines,
}
\mysection Section~1 & \\
    1 & Line A \\
    2 & Line B \\
    3 & Line C \\
\mysection Section~2 & \\
    4 & Line A \\
    5 & Line B \\
    6 & Line C \\
\mysection Section~3 & \\
    7 & Line A \\
    8 & Line B \\
    9 & Line C \\
\mysection Section~4 & \\
    10 & Line A \\
    11 & Line B \\
    12 & Line C \\
\mysection Section~5 & \\
    13 & Line A \\
    14 & Line B \\
    15 & Line C \\
\mysection Section~6 & \\
    16 & Line A \\
    17 & Line B \\
    18 & Line C \\
\mysection Section~7 & \\
    19 & Line A \\
    20 & Line B \\
    21 & Line C \\
\mysection Section~8 & \\ \nopagebreak
    22 & Line A \\ \nopagebreak
    23 & Line B \\ \nopagebreak
    24 & Line C \\ \nopagebreak
\mysection Section~9 & \\
    25 & Line A \\
    26 & Line B \\
    27 & Line C \\
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]